# How to configure google app engine on gradle IntelliJ Kotlin "JS Client and JVM Server" project?

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, kotlin

I would like to create a Kotlin project where the client site is JS and the server side is a Google App Engine standard enviroment application.

On IntelliJ, exist a New Project Kotlin option called "JS Client and JVM Server | Gradle". This project creates this build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.40'
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    mavenCentral()
}
def ktor_version = '1.1.3'
def logback_version = '1.2.3'

kotlin {
    jvm()
    js {
        browser {
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-common')
                implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
            }
        }
        jvmMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-jdk8')
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
                implementation "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
                implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
            }
        }
        jvmTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test')
                implementation kotlin('test-junit')
            }
        }
        jsMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('stdlib-js')
            }
        }
        jsTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation kotlin('test-js')
            }
        }
    }
}

jvmJar {
    dependsOn(jsBrowserWebpack)
    from(new File(jsBrowserWebpack.entry.name, jsBrowserWebpack.outputPath))
}

task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [jvmJar]) {
    group = "application"
    main = "sample.SampleJvmKt"
    classpath(configurations.jvmRuntimeClasspath, jvmJar)
    args = []
}
```

How to configure jvmMain for Google App Engine standard environment? How to integrate the build.gradle configuration specified in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8) on jvmMain?